# Laravel 5.2 validation redirect with old input

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

In reference to [this stockoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107118/laravel-5-1-4-validation-fail-not-populating-old-data-when-using-restful-routes)

I created a new request with `php artisan make:request ApplicationFormRequest`

```
public function rules() { 
   return ['first_name' => 'required']
}
```

I also have a controller as such,

```
public function store(ApplicationFormRequest $request){
   //empty
}
```

I have seen an example on stackoverflow with

```
return Redirect::to('/')->withInput();
```

they seem to put their validation together with the controller, but I am not sure how to go about it this way.

Where would I put that? How do I retrieve old input even with validation fail?

EDIT you see my controller is empty, it validate automatically with the rule i set at ApplicationFormRequest.  when it failed it automatically redirect to the view where the input is submitted with error

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <li class="alert label">{{$error}}</li>
@endforeach
```

but I am unable to fill the input with the input user just submitted, I try to do

```
<input type="text" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" \>
```

but this give me error `Use of undefined constant`

Comment: Your question is very vague. What does the Redirect example mean? What do you mean "put their validation together with the controller?"

Comment: I try to clarified it in my question please take a look, let me know if there is anything that is unclear.

Comment: Check a value exists. I don't know how is it done in Laravel, but it should look something like this `if(old('first_name')!=""){echo old('first_name');}else{}`

Comment: @user3284463 thanks, but I don't know where to pass my first_name variable back in.  as I stated in the question I have seen people do `return Redirect::to('/')->withInput();` but I don't know how in my case.

Comment: Is this a multi-step form or an edit form?

Comment: @user3284463 it is a single step form. But as validation fail it will be redirected to the same page. But with all previous input deleted. I want to keep the input for user to fix.

Comment: Okay... Check if the POST or GET has a value by using `input::has("first_name") ` and if does, then echo to input value which would look like `{{ Input::get('name') }}` else do nothing

Comment: @user3284463 I try `{{old('last_name')}}` after I took a shower it just magically work... I have no ideas why, yet I tried that so many times before. thanks guys.

Comment: Great. My answer is just a long cut to  the `old` function. lol

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2, if the view forms are not being populated with old data sent back from a custom `Request` class, do the following:

1) Place all routes related to the request in the route group, which should be included in 5.2

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // routes here
});
```

2) Run `php artisan key:generate`

---

**EDIT:** This fix may not be applicable for versions other than 5.2.

Credits:

[Laravel - Session store not set on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

[No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.](http://laravel.io/forum/06-09-2015-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid)

[Another relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362150/laravel-5-2-form-validation-request)

Answer (score 0):

as the error say use of undefined constant. Your errors variable is not in the scope of view. check what you are doing wrong.

use [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#old-input) for further reading.

Comment: I think what I did wrong is not passing the old input back, but since the app do it automaticlly I don't know where to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking if a value is available in the POST or GET array first. If it is available in the POST or GET array, then echo it in the `value` attribute of the input.

Your input field would look something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="if (Input::has('first_name')){ @echo Input::get('first_name');}" \>
```